# error installing xively-python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, xively

I'm following the first time use tutorial for xively on a raspberry pi from the xively site. When I enter the command `pip install xively-python` I get an error:

> could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xively-python

Anyone else experience this?

I'm completely stuck now. Any suggestion on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

[The Xively/Raspberry Pi docs](https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/pi/#start-building-the-app) say to do this:

```
pip install --pre xively-python
```